# How to cd open / autocomplete a folder that ends in a specific phrase

Tags: bash, wildcards, autocomplete, cd-command

I have a folder with subfolders named like this:

```
1122334 important things
1122335 less important things
1122336 notes
1122337 pictures of kittens
```

etc

The numbers at the beginning are date codes. If it was up to me, I would put the date codes at the end, but it isn't.

In bash, I'd like to do something like this:

```
$ cd *pictu<tab>
```

and get this

```
$ cd 1122337\ pictures\ of\ kittens/
```

Is there a simple way to do this, or something I can put in my `.bashrc` to make this possible?

Comment: I just found out that `zsh` can do this. Another option would be to `cd *pic*` which will move you to the directory but not tab expand its name.

Comment: Awesome! It looks like bash will do the same thing. I wonder if there is a way to get autocomplete to work with it.

Comment: I meant that bash will allow you to cd into a directory with `cd *pic*` if that expands to a single directory, zsh can also tab expand the name if you start typing `pic<TAB>` which bash won't. If that is all you needed should I post it as an answer?

Comment: Ah! Sorry I misread that. In bash if I do cd *pic*<TAB> it will autocomplete for me. Yes, post this as an answer! (Thanks!!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way of making bash autocomplete `*pictu`, but here are some workarounds:

1. Don't use <kbd>TAB</kbd>, just `cd` directly using wildcards before and after the pattern:

   ```
   $ cd *pictu*
   ```

   That will move you into the first directory whose name contains `pictu`.
2. Use two wildcards and *then* <kbd>TAB</kbd>:

   ```
   $ cd *pictu*<TAB>
   ```

   That should expand to `cd 1122337\ pictures\ of\ kittens/`
3. Use another shell. `zsh` has a cool feature, you can do:

   ```
   ➜ cd pictu<tab>
   ```

   and that expands to `➜ cd 1122337\ pictures\ of\ kittens/`.

Comment: Note that in order for `$ cd *pictu*<TAB>` to expand in `bash`, the `bashdefault` completion option has to be set for `cd`: `compopt -o bashdefault cd`. You can review the currently set completion options with the command `complete -p cd`.

Comment: @ThomasNyman could you elaborate on that please? On my system, `complete -p cd` shows that I have `nospace` on and nothing else but I can auto complete `cd *bar*` to `cd fobarfoo`.

Comment: I tested this on Ubuntu 12.04 with `bash` 4.2.25 and for me the two-wildcard-expansion does not work without adding the `bashdefault` completion option. I have `nospace` set also, and on Ubuntu, installing the `bash-completion` package adds a `_cd` completion function as well, but these do not seem to affect the behaviour in my case.

Comment: @ThomasNyman I'm on `bash` 4.2.45, `complete -p cd` returns `complete -o nospace -F _cd cd` but the two-wildcard-expansion works. It might be because of the newer `bash` I guess.